# I am not able to get the data from mongodb using python

Tags: python-3.x

This is the below code:

```
import sys
from pymongo import MongoClient
import json
def main ():

     # Connection to the MongoDB Server
     mongoClient = MongoClient ('localhost:27017')
     # Connection to the database
     db = mongoClient.Botdata

     Botdata = db.Botdata
     collection = db.intent

     details = collection.find ({"intents": "patterns"})
     #docs = list(Botdata.find({'intents': 'tag'}))

     print(details)



if __name__ == "__main__":
         main ()
```

The main issue is whenever I run this code I get this type of error:

```
<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x7f31623955f8>
```

The thing is I have stored the data in mongodb but while retrieving the same data this code is showing this error please help.

Comment: If you only want one result try `find_one` instead of `find` else you have to iterate through all the results in the cursor I believe. Also have a read through the mongodb docs on using python https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/getting-started-with-python-and-mongodb

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a cursor object just iterate over it. you will find the relevant records.

```
details = collection.find ({"intents": "patterns"})
for data in details:
    print(data)
```